# HTML treat code within brackets as PHP code

Tags: php

I am building my website completely in PHP. I am trying to make it as much flexible as possible.

I have seen there are some softwares made in PHP that are able to get a HTML page, and before showing it, the PHP code recognizes the code inside brackets `{PHP Code}` as PHP code, runs it and only then shows the final page.

```
<h1>Hi My Name is {echo $name}</h1>
```

How can I achieve the same? I know there is Smarty Code. But I do not want to learn Smarty, I just want to know how to check a HTML page with PHP, find every bracket and threat that as PHP before showing the page..?

Can you point me somewhere?

Comment: Can you clarify what "threat" means here?

Comment: Suspect that "threat" might be a typo for "treat"

Comment: Might want to take a look at Mustache for PHP: https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php  (both for code ideas, or for another way of doing things).

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for PHP's basic syntax?

If you enable [`short_open_tags`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) (it usually is enabled by default), this will work:

```
<h1>Hi My Name is <?=$name?></h1>
```

otherwise, this will *always* work:

```
<h1>Hi My Name is <?php echo $name; ?></h1>
```

PHP is already a templating language - there often is no need to add *another* layer of templating on top of it.

Comment: no I want to keep the template files separated from the php engine..as smarty does.

Comment: @Diego are you sure you don't want to use Smarty then? It solves a lot of additional problems (like caching) and is relatively easy to learn. (Unless you want to learn how to build a template engine, which is different and totally okay of course.)

Answer (score 2):

> I want to keep the template files separated from the php engine

**In fact, you don't**

Your template files would behave as native PHP files in every way.
So, there is asolutely no [logical] reason to prefer such a strange solution over native PHP.

Comment: Well, I believe he means separating logic from presentation, which makes sense to me.

Comment: whatever he means, this is failed attempt. There is no sense in separating "logic" from "presentation" anyway. What is that "presentation"? How can you present whatever real life information without applying a ligic?

Comment: I believe model-view-controller pattern makes sense.

Comment: It makes. Like nearly thousand other patterns do. So what?

Comment: So it is not true that "There is no sense in separating "logic" from "presentation" anyway".

Comment: This famous pattern does not separate "logic" from "presentation". it uses logic everywhere: there is logic in the View (which is responsible for the presentation) as well as in the Model and in Controller. if you want to separate something, better call it "to separate business logic from presentation logic"

Answer (score 1):

use the php tags for the echo statement.

```
<h1>Hi my name is <?php echo $name; ?></h1>
```

Comment: the file also needs to be saved as a php file. example: index.php

Answer (score 1):

Well, just point apache to index.php which [includes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) phtml templates into itself. Use `<?php ?>` instead of `{ }`.